# How do I flip my finished eyeball to the other side?

Tags: modeling, rigging

I just finished creating an eyeball with procedural textures fully rigged and everything, and I'm trying to duplicate it on the opposite eye and I've had a frustrating time and it's not working at all.

I tried duplicating the left eyeball, selecting the eye then pressing <kbd>R</kbd> for rotate, <kbd>S</kbd> for scale, <kbd>X</kbd> for x-Axis and negative 1 and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and the eyeball ended up exactly in the right eye in the correct position, but it's parented to the left eye.

When I try to clear the old parent of the right eye and parent it to the right eye bone, the eyeball jumps really high up above the character! I tried to manually put it in its socket, and eventually, I got it to work, but then when I apply the rotation, location and scale, the eyeball turns around 180 degrees and the procedural texture is backwards on the eyeball.

Is this supposed to be this complicated? Is there an easy way to transfer the eyeball to the other side without all these problems? Thanks in advance.

Comment: While i believe that you can skip the rotating and only use the scaling, i think the main problem might have come when you cleared the parent (most likely without keeping the transformation) and then parented it again (similar without keeping the transformation).

Comment: You're right the order of how I did it was wrong.  I ended up duplicating the eyeball, unparented it with alt+p and kept the transformation, then S to scale -1 on the x axis, flipped the normals, applied location rotation and scale, reparented it with empty groups, assigned the eye.r bone full influence to the right eye ball, cleaned up the vertex groups and removed everything except the eye.r bone, renamed its materials, and now it finally works. It’s a longer process than I thought but still easier than creating the eyeball again haha Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked, do allow me to encourage you writing the steps of how you solved it as an answer to close the question. This would help others find the solution (maybe to a similar problem of theirs), and understand it easier as well since an answer by the one who had and solved the situation is usually pointing out the key problems best.